# Java Regex to match Chinese and/or ordinary numbers

Tags: java, regex

Actually the regex I have matches anything *but* the Chinese but it matches the numbers too, which I don't want. As you can see in the regex demo here, the number 45 is matched but I need it to be excluded too.

https://regex101.com/r/XNtD12/1

Current regex is: `(?!\p{IsHan}\n)[^\p{IsHan}\n？。，？！]+`

Desired output:

```
He is 45 today <- matched 100%
你今天45岁了 <- not matched at all
这个句子没有数字 <- not matched at all
Ok I see <- matched 100%
```

Java code being used:

```
String example = "He is 45 today\n你今天45岁了\n这个句子没有数字\nOk I see";
System.out.println(example.replaceAll("^[^\\p{IsHan}\\n？。，？！]+$", ""));
```

Comment: You don't need the lookahead and you can exclude digits 0-9 `[^\p{IsHan}\n？。，？！0-9]+` https://regex101.com/r/4sDKgw/1

Comment: @The fourth bird That doesn't work if there are any numeric characters in the non Chinese lines. Updated my regex demo to reflect that.

Comment: Non Chinese lines like this? `^[^\p{IsHan}\n？。，？！]+$` https://regex101.com/r/tOFiKD/1

Comment: @The fourth bird That words in a regex101 demo but doesn't work in actual java code, it literally does nothing. I had another regex that worked in regex101 but not in actually java code. My solution above works in actual java code but leaves the numbers in. Any idea why your solution wouldn't work in actual java code? I'm just using `replaceAll`.

Comment: Did you write it as `String regex = "^[^\\p{IsHan}\\n？。，？！]+$";` with a doubled backslash?

Comment: @The fourth bird Yes, it won't run if I don't do that, it will just throw an error.

Comment: What is the error? And how are you using the code?

Comment: @The fourth bird I added the code I used to my question, maybe there's something I missed. There's no error it just doesn't alter the text in any way.

Comment: Ah, you have to enable multiline with for example `(?m)` like `System.out.println(example.replaceAll("(?m)^[^\\p{IsHan}\\n？。，？！]+$", ""));` due to the anchors.

Comment: @The fourth bird Aha that was it, great thanks very much. You should post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern you can omit the lookahead `(?!\p{IsHan}\n)` as the directly following negated character class already does not match `\p{IsHan}`

If you don't want partial matches, you can add anchors to the start and the end of the pattern, and enable multiline using an inline modifier `(?m)`

```
String example = "He is 45 today\n你今天45岁了\n这个句子没有数字\nOk I see";
System.out.println(example.replaceAll("(?m)^[^\\p{IsHan}\\n？。，？！]+$", ""));
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tOFiKD/1) and a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/x2TzBk)

If you want to remove optional trailing newlines using replaceAll:

```
^[^\\p{IsHan}\\n？。，？！]+$\\R?
```